# primefaces: actionListener and redirection at the same time

Tags: java, primefaces

I would like when I click on a

```
   <p:commandButton>
```

,a Bean for processing is called and at the same time, the page should be redirected to another page.

In other words, I would like to combine:

```
<p:commandButton actionListener="#{processBean.process}" >
</p:commandButton>
```

And:

```
<h:link outcome="redirection"> 
</h:link>
```

where "redirection" is configured in faces-config.xml

How should I do ?
Is there a better way to achieve this ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `action` property of `p:commandButton.`

```
<p:commandButton actionListener="#{processBean.process}" >
</p:commandButton>
```

change it to

```
<p:commandButton actionListener="#{processBean.process}" action="viewIDToRedirect" >
</p:commandButton>
```

First, `actionListener` will be called then navigation will kick in. But remember you'll need to define the Navigation rule in `faces-config.xml`

Comment: Glad it helped you. Accept this as answer then :)

Comment: @Makky I'm having same requirement.. and if any validation errors at server side,  should stay on the same page with validation message else redirect to mentioned page in action attribute.. Present even there are validation error messages, it is redirecting.. Help me to solve this.

Comment: @Mr.Chowdary look at my answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21785344/primefaces-redirection-and-action-at-the-same-using-defaultmenuitem/21786155#21786155

Comment: @Mr.Chowdary in my answer the method returns string that's action id now you can check there if any error then return null

Answer (score 2):

Use `action` attribute, but don't keep `actionListener` anymore.

```
<p:commandButton action="#{processBean.process}" />
```

To perform the action without validating the form (eg. DELETE), you could then use process attribute as follows:

```
<p:commandButton action="#{processBean.process}" process="@this" />
```

Note returning the target link with `faces-redirect=true`

```
public String process() {
    ...
    return "/path/to/some.xhtml?faces-redirect=true";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, none of the before exposed solutions worked for me because I'm using p:layout. So, I had a p:panelMenu in the west p:layoutUnit and my main form was in the center p:layoutUnit. Then, when I tried to navigated  to another page, the Menu returned to its initial state and I don't know why.

My solution by now is to simulate a click with jQuery from the action method in the backing bean in this way:

`RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().execute("$('#menuItemId').click()");`

Now I can keep the state of the p:panelMenu and navigate to the desired page.

In the first question, you also can click the link with jQuery. I know that every scenario is different but in any case you can use a jQuery call from the backing bean.