# primefaces redirection and action at the same using DefaultMenuItem

Tags: java, primefaces

I woud like to use the redirection and action at the same using  DefaultMenuItem

My code is

```
MenuModel menuModel = new DefaultMenuModel();

DefaultSubMenu menu = new DefaultSubMenu("menu");

DefaultMenuItem item = new DefaultMenuItem("new Menu"); 

item.setCommand("redirection"); // redirection is configured in faces-config.xml

item.setCommand("#{myBean.init}"); 

menu.addElement(item)

menuModel.addElement(menu);
```

but it does not work

(it worked previsouly when there was no

```
 item.setCommand("#{myBean.init}");
```

)

Apparently, having two setCommand gives some problems

but I need the inialization when I click on the button.

Could you help me ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
 item.setCommand("#{myBean.init}");
```

In your manage bean `myBean` you can have `init` method like

```
public String init(){

   //do your business logic.

   return "idToBeNavigatedTo";

}
```

Above will process your business Logic and `redirect` to `url` which is mapped for the action id you return in `faces-config.xml`

Comment: yes ! Thanks a lot ! That's twice you save the day today !