# primefaces p:commandButton using both actionListener and action attrributes

Tags: ajax, jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I'm using `jsf 2` and `primefaces 4`.
I have gone through the following link [Click Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21782427/primefaces-actionlistener-and-redirection-at-the-same-time) and used in my application, `actionListener` for executing validation logic as well as business logic .
`action` attribute for redirecting.

So for it is fine but if i get any validation errors, i must show them on the same page. This means it is ajax response.
I tested this case, even there are validation errors, it is redirecting to another page as mentioned in `action` attribute

if no validation errors, it should be redirected to another page, this is not ajax response in this case.
So how to handle both the situations ?
Any help is highly appreciated

Comment: Why to complicate things ? just call the action method and inside the action do your validation, and based on the result you decide where to point the user, either return nothing if validation fails or redirect.

Comment: @HatemAlimam Thanks for your idea and i tested it. working as expected. one more thing, how can i pass a param to the new page to show notification of operation performed in previous page ?

Comment: Use [`f:param`](http://www.mkyong.com/jsf2/jsf-2-param-example/)

Comment: If you want a confirmation message on the next page you can try to add a global FacesMessage as normal and use FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getFlash().setKeepMessages(true); Worked for me once but don't remember the circumstances

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have implemented this by instructions given in comments by **@Hatem Alimam** and **@Jaqen H'ghar**.
**solution:**
I used `action` to execute validations and business logic and redirecting based on `success` or `errors`.
After redirecting to another page, showing notification using `flash scope` is useful a lot.

```
FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getFlash().setKeepMessage‌​s(true);
```